# Android App window keeps splashing

Tags: android, android-activity, memory-leaks, picasso

We are using picasso v2.5.2, viewpager, fragment activity, in our app.

Our app keep splashing and restarting activity again and again (hang> went black> activityRestart> black app window> activity restart) if I press back button continously then It go back. What's the reason? It silently crash and restart same activity?

It always occurred when user open too many apps and keep it open by pressing home key in tablet Samsung T230, Android 4.4.2 and reopen our app.
After dumping memory [HeapHero](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hm6BS0d7poFJLg7qdItVVYlOLngHT6ET/view?usp=sharing) pointing to memory leaks in picasso but I'm not sure what is causing this. [Picasso issue](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1932)

Logs during splashing or restarting activity
with package filter

```
06-26 12:24:16.446 18083-18083/com.abccompany.xyzapp D/Picasso: Main        errored      [R1246]+980ms 
06-26 12:24:16.456 18083-18083/com.abccompany.xyzapp D/Picasso: Main        errored      [R1267]+629ms 
06-26 12:24:16.456 18083-18083/com.abccompany.xyzapp W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:394)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:136)
        at com.squareup.picasso.UrlConnectionDownloader.load(UrlConnectionDownloader.java:93)
        at com.squareup.picasso.NetworkRequestHandler.load(NetworkRequestHandler.java:47)
        at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:206)
        at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
        at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:411)
06-26 12:24:16.456 18083-18083/com.abccompany.xyzapp D/Picasso: Main        errored      [R1247]+979ms 
06-26 12:24:16.456 18083-18083/com.abccompany.xyzapp W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:394)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:136)
        at com.squareup.picasso.UrlConnectionDownloader.load(UrlConnectionDownloader.java:93)
        at com.squareup.picasso.NetworkRequestHandler.load(NetworkRequestHandler.java:47)
        at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:206)
        at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
        at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:411)
06-26 12:24:16.456 18083-18083/com.abccompany.xyzapp D/Picasso: Main        errored      [R1248]+975ms 
06-26 12:24:16.456 18083-18083/com.abccompany.xyzapp W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:394)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:136)
        at com.squareup.picasso.UrlConnectionDownloader.load(UrlConnectionDownloader.java:93)
        at com.squareup.picasso.NetworkRequestHandler.load(NetworkRequestHandler.java:47)
        at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:206)
        at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
        at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:411)
06-26 12:24:16.466 18083-18083/com.abccompany.xyzapp D/Picasso: Main        errored      [R1249]+971ms 
06-26 12:24:16.466 18083-18083/com.abccompany.xyzapp W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:394)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:136)
        at com.squareup.picasso.UrlConnectionDownloader.load(UrlConnectionDownloader.java:93)
        at com.squareup.picasso.NetworkRequestHandler.load(NetworkRequestHandler.java:47)
        at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:206)
        at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
        at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:411)
06-26 12:24:16.466 18083-18083/com.abccompany.xyzapp D/Picasso: Main        errored      [R1250]+967ms 
06-26 12:24:16.466 18083-18083/com.abccompany.xyzapp W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:394)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:136)
        at com.squareup.picasso.UrlConnectionDownloader.load(UrlConnectionDownloader.java:93)
        at com.squareup.picasso.NetworkRequestHandler.load(NetworkRequestHandler.java:47)
        at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:206)
        at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
        at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:411)
06-26 12:24:16.466 18083-18083/com.abccompany.xyzapp D/Picasso: Main        errored      [R1251]+964ms 
06-26 12:24:16.466 18083-18083/com.abccompany.xyzapp W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:394)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:136)
        at com.squareup.picasso.UrlConnectionDownloader.load(UrlConnectionDownloader.java:93)
        at com.squareup.picasso.NetworkRequestHandler.load(NetworkRequestHandler.java:47)
        at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:206)
        at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

no filter and

```
class.06-26 11:27:14.751 1050-1050/? E/GCoreFlp: Bound FusedProviderService with LocationManager
06-26 11:27:14.761 577-656/? D/LocationProviderProxy: applying state to connected service
    applying state to connected service
06-26 11:27:14.791 143-143/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=238 createSurf (1x1),1 flag=404, DouponDetai
06-26 11:27:14.791 577-3981/? I/SpenGestureManager: setFocusWindow21170
06-26 11:27:14.802 8089-8089/? W/System.err: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_REMOVE_NAVIGATION
06-26 11:27:14.802 734-970/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
06-26 11:27:14.802 734-970/? I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: visibility is same
06-26 11:27:14.802 956-1658/? W/GAV4: Thread[Thread-62,5,main]:  Using destination https://ssl.google-analytics.com
06-26 11:27:14.802 8089-8089/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:724)
        at com.sec.android.gallery3d.util.GalleryFeature.checkSystemUiVisibility(GalleryFeature.java:1680)
        at com.sec.android.gallery3d.util.GalleryFeature.init(GalleryFeature.java:339)
        at com.sec.android.gallery3d.app.GalleryAppImpl.getDataManager(GalleryAppImpl.java:263)
        at com.sec.android.gallery3d.provider.GalleryProvider.onCreate(GalleryProvider.java:126)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1591)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1562)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4828)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4711)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:175)
06-26 11:27:14.812 8089-8089/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 11:27:14.822 734-826/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
06-26 11:27:14.822 734-826/? I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: visibility is same
06-26 11:27:14.822 577-654/? D/PointerIcon: setMouseIconStyle1 pointerType: 1001iconType:101 flag:0
    setMouseCustomIcon IconType is same.101
06-26 11:27:14.842 7601-7601/com.abccompany.xyzapp E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
06-26 11:27:14.842 7601-7601/com.abccompany.xyzapp D/Picasso: Main        canceled     [R49]+21s target got garbage collected
06-26 11:27:14.852 7601-7601/com.abccompany.xyzapp D/Picasso: Main        canceled     [R50]+21s target got garbage collected
06-26 11:27:14.852 734-826/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
06-26 11:27:14.852 734-826/? I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: visibility is same
06-26 11:27:14.852 577-8103/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1509 com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService$4.run:2684 java.lang.Thread.run:841 <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> 
06-26 11:27:14.892 8089-8089/? D/Spen: SpenSdk jar version = 55
    SpenSdk apk version = 3.0.91
    Server UPDATE Check
06-26 11:27:14.892 8089-8089/? W/linker: libSPenBase.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
06-26 11:27:14.892 8089-8089/? D/SPenError: JNI_OnLoad
06-26 11:27:14.902 8089-8089/? D/JNI_Bitmap: Init .. Done
06-26 11:27:14.902 8089-8089/? D/SPenSpiDecoder: JNI_OnLoad .. Done
06-26 11:27:14.902 8089-8089/? D/SPenError: JNI_OnLoad Success
06-26 11:27:14.902 8089-8089/? D/PluginManager: Registering com/samsung/android/sdk/pen/plugin/framework/JniPluginManager natives
    Registering com/samsung/android/sdk/pen/plugin/framework/SpenPluginManager$PluginListener natives
06-26 11:27:14.902 8089-8089/? D/Init_SPenSdk_Jni: JNI_OnLoad
    JNI_OnLoad .. Done
06-26 11:27:14.912 8089-8089/? D/Model_ObjectBase_Jni: JNI_OnLoad .. Done
06-26 11:27:14.912 8089-8089/? D/Model_ObjectStroke_Jni: JNI_OnLoad .. Done
06-26 11:27:14.912 8089-8089/? D/Model_ObjectImage_Jni: JNI_OnLoad .. Done
06-26 11:27:14.912 8089-8089/? D/Model_ObjectText_Jni: JNI_OnLoad .. Done
06-26 11:27:14.912 8089-8089/? D/Model_ObjectContainer_Jni: JNI_OnLoad .. Done
06-26 11:27:14.912 8089-8089/? D/Model_PageDoc_Jni: JNI_OnLoad .. Done
06-26 11:27:14.912 8089-8089/? D/Model_NoteDoc_Jni: check build type eng[0]
    JNI_OnLoad .. Done
06-26 11:27:14.912 8089-8089/? D/Model_NoteFile_Jni: JNI_OnLoad .. Done
06-26 11:27:14.912 8089-8089/? D/Model_ObjectUtil_Jni: JNI_OnLoad .. Done
06-26 11:27:14.912 8089-8089/? D/Model: OnLoad class Done
06-26 11:27:14.922 8089-8089/? D/dalvikvm: No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libSPenSkia.so 0x41dc1c80, skipping init
06-26 11:27:14.922 8089-8089/? D/SPen_Library: Draw Engine JNI_OnLoad enter!!
    Canvas JNI_OnLoad enter!!
06-26 11:27:14.932 8089-8089/? D/SPen_Library: Canvas JNI_OnLoad Success
    TextView JNI_OnLoad enter!!
    TextView JNI_OnLoad Success
    Text JNI_OnLoad enter!!
    Text JNI_OnLoad Success
    FontManager JNI_OnLoad enter!!
    FontManager JNI_OnLoad Success
    CapturePage JNI_OnLoad enter!!
    CapturePage JNI_OnLoad Success
    Multi JNI_OnLoad enter!!
    Multi JNI_OnLoad Success
    Draw Engine JNI_OnLoad Success
06-26 11:27:14.942 8089-8089/? D/SPen_Library: Brush JNI_OnLoad enter!!
06-26 11:27:14.942 734-747/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
06-26 11:27:14.942 734-747/? I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: visibility is same
06-26 11:27:14.942 8089-8089/? D/SPen_Library: Brush JNI_OnLoad Success
    ChineseBrush JNI_OnLoad enter!!
    ChineseBrush JNI_OnLoad Success
06-26 11:27:14.952 8089-8089/? D/SPen_Library: InkPen JNI_OnLoad enter!!
06-26 11:27:14.952 7601-7601/com.abccompany.xyzapp W/test: application is in foreground: false
06-26 11:27:14.952 8089-8089/? D/SPen_Library: InkPen JNI_OnLoad Success
    Marker JNI_OnLoad enter!!
    Marker JNI_OnLoad Success
06-26 11:27:14.962 8089-8089/? D/SPen_Library: Pencil JNI_OnLoad enter!!
    Pencil JNI_OnLoad Success
06-26 11:27:14.962 7601-7601/com.abccompany.xyzapp W/test: application is visible: false
06-26 11:27:14.962 8089-8089/? D/SPen_Library: NativePen JNI_OnLoad enter!!
    NativePen JNI_OnLoad Success
06-26 11:27:14.962 734-826/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
06-26 11:27:14.962 734-826/? I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: visibility is same
06-26 11:27:14.962 8089-8089/? D/SPen_Library: MagicPen JNI_OnLoad enter!!
    MagicPen JNI_OnLoad Success
06-26 11:27:14.972 143-203/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=238 Removed DouponDetai (38/39)
06-26 11:27:14.972 143-674/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=238 Removed DouponDetai (-2/39)
06-26 11:27:14.972 734-748/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
06-26 11:27:14.972 734-748/? I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: visibility is same
06-26 11:27:14.972 8089-8089/? W/linker: libSPenHSV.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
06-26 11:27:14.982 8089-8089/? D/dalvikvm: No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libSPenHSV.so 0x41dc1c80, skipping init
    No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libSPenVIRecognition.so 0x41dc1c80, skipping init
    No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libSPenVITextAll.so 0x41dc1c80, skipping init
06-26 11:27:14.982 8089-8089/? D/Spen: SpenSdk Libraries are loaded.
06-26 11:27:14.982 8089-8089/? D/Init_SPenSdk_Jni: SPenSdk_init2
06-26 11:27:14.982 8089-8089/? D/Init_SPenSdk: Init - screen_width = 800, screen_height = 1280, maxCacheSize = 5 M
    Total S Pen SDK Directory Size = 0
06-26 11:27:14.982 8089-8089/? D/Spen: initialize complete
06-26 11:27:14.982 577-654/? D/PointerIcon: setMouseIconStyle1 pointerType: 1001iconType:101 flag:0
    setMouseCustomIcon IconType is same.101
06-26 11:27:14.992 8089-8089/? W/ContextImpl: Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.sec.knox.containeragent.service.containerinstallermanager.ContainerInstallerManagerService } android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService:529 com.sec.knox.containeragent.ContainerInstallerManager.<init>:64 com.sec.android.gallery3d.util.GalleryUtils.setKNOXInstallMode:2192 
06-26 11:27:14.992 734-734/? D/PhoneStatusBar: setTransGradationMode=false, mTransparentMode=false, mSemiTransparentMode=false, mMultiWindowMode=false
06-26 11:27:14.992 577-3981/? W/ActivityManager: Permission Denial: getCurrentUser() from pid=7601, uid=10157 requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
06-26 11:27:14.992 577-911/? D/StatusBarManagerService: tr p:7601,o:f
06-26 11:27:14.992 577-1197/? W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=com.sec.knox.containeragent.service.containerinstallermanager.ContainerInstallerManagerService } U=0: not found
06-26 11:27:15.002 7601-7601/com.abccompany.xyzapp I/FacebookEventLog: inside trackscreen Event:View Coupon Detail param: C. Big King
06-26 11:27:15.012 8089-8089/? D/NearbySource: Nearby Source Create!
06-26 11:27:15.022 8089-8089/? D/NearbyContext: Nearby Context Create!
06-26 11:27:15.042 138-333/? E/cutils: Failed to mkdirat(/storage/extSdCard/Android): Read-only file system
06-26 11:27:15.042 8089-8089/? W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.sec.android.gallery3d/cache
06-26 11:27:15.042 138-333/? W/Vold: Returning OperationFailed - no handler for errno 30
06-26 11:27:15.112 734-734/? D/PhoneStatusBar: setSemiTransparentMode=false, mTransparentMode=false, mSemiTransparentMode=false, mMultiWindowMode=false
06-26 11:27:15.112 577-910/? D/StatusBarManagerService: semi p:7601,o:f
06-26 11:27:15.162 956-1658/? W/GAV4: Thread[Thread-62,5,main]:  Using destination https://ssl.google-analytics.com
```

Answer (score -1):

you are using the abc.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com package or class but it can not find out by the program. so you have to define this in the mainfest with the particular activity. 
second if you press back button and it goes to privious activity then you are using onbackpressed method in your activity. and provide action as you want

Comment: Bro this just for example. I change company and app name too.